# USB tethering broken after attempting to install Huion 1060 Plus on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, android, tethering

I attempted to install Huion 1060 Plus on Ubuntu by following [these instructions](https://www.facebook.com/huion/posts/how-to-install-huion-1060-plus-on-ubuntu-1704sudo-apt-get-install-linux-headers-/2042579912628124/), however after rebooting USB tethering from my Android to the PC is not working anymore with the status saying "cable unplugged".

> sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r`
> sudo apt install git
> git clone https://github.com/kolrabi/digimend-kernel-drivers.git
> cd digimend-kernel-drivers
> make
> sudo rmmod hid-kye
> sudo rmmod hid-uclogic
> sudo rmmod hid-huion
> sudo make uninstall
> sudo make install
>
> Reconnect the tablet or reboot the machine

This is a huge problem for me as this is currently my only source of internet connection. I have tried restarting my phone and computer with no positive result. Also tethering still works on the partition of my PC dual boot with Windows 10 installed.

I have tried Googling this, and am currently completely lost. Has anyone got an idea or can point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm stacked too